# C++: is the nepero constant definite somewhere?

Tags: c++

In the library `math.h` **π** is defined throgh `M_PI`. Is there a similar constant defining the Napier's constant (Euler's number) *e* (the basis of the natural logarithm) ?

Comment: The constant for `e` is `M_E`, [at least as far as Visual Studio is concerned](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/math-constants), though technically none of these macros are part of the standard.

Comment: Technically, the macro `M_PI` (or any of the other `M_` prefixed macros) is not specified in the C++ (or C) specification. It's a *somewhat* common extension of the language.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: It's not just a somewhat common extension, more specifically they're defined by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/math.h.html) standard

Comment: There would have been a *very* simple way to find this out yourself: Find the `<cmath>` header file and *look inside it*.

Comment: "Nepero" apparently is Italian for Napier, and in English the constant is better known as Euler's number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While M_PI presents in some compiliers, it is not standard.  Another non-standard constant is M_E.  It may or may not be present in your compilier.

In GCC 5.4, both constants are defined if you use -std=gnu99 or -std=gnu11 but not if you use -std=c99 or -std=c11:

```
# define M_E            2.7182818284590452354   /* e */
# define M_LOG2E        1.4426950408889634074   /* log_2 e */
# define M_LOG10E       0.43429448190325182765  /* log_10 e */
# define M_LN2          0.69314718055994530942  /* log_e 2 */
# define M_LN10         2.30258509299404568402  /* log_e 10 */
# define M_PI           3.14159265358979323846  /* pi */
# define M_PI_2         1.57079632679489661923  /* pi/2 */
# define M_PI_4         0.78539816339744830962  /* pi/4 */
# define M_1_PI         0.31830988618379067154  /* 1/pi */
# define M_2_PI         0.63661977236758134308  /* 2/pi */
# define M_2_SQRTPI     1.12837916709551257390  /* 2/sqrt(pi) */
# define M_SQRT2        1.41421356237309504880  /* sqrt(2) */
# define M_SQRT1_2      0.70710678118654752440  /* 1/sqrt(2) */
```

Answer (score 3):

There's of course the obvious `exp(1)`. 100% portable, and modern compilers don't bother calling an actual function for that but just put in the constant.